# I'm not sure why `Logger` is not defined when I'm going over a JS Mixin pattern tutorial

Tags: javascript, logging, mixins

I'm trying to learn some programming and I was going over [this](http://bob.yexley.net/dry-javascript-with-mixins/) tutorial and I got this error in the console `ReferenceError: Logger is not defined --> }(Logger))`. I think the main difference between the tut's code and mine is that the tutorial uses underscore's extend and I thought I would use an extend method(function) that I found somewhere else.

```
    function extend(destination, source){
        for(var k in source){
            if(source.hasOwnProperty(k)){
                destination[k] = source[k];
            }
        }
        return destination;
    }
    (function () {
        var Logger = {
            log: function (message) {
                if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function") {
                    console.log(message);
                }
            }
        };

        return Logger;
    }());

    (function ( Logger) {
        var MyObject = function () {
            this.doSomething = function () {
                this.log("My Object is doing something!");
            };
        };

        // This copies the members of the `Logger` object onto the prototype of `MyObject`
        extend(MyObject.prototype, Logger);

        return MyObject;
    }(Logger))

    var obj = new MyObject();
    obj.doSomething();
```

Maybe the problem is I don't know how to use self invoking anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Logger` is not defined because you have it as a local variable inside the first self invoking function.  To make it available, you should do this:

```
var Logger = (function () {
        var Logger = {
            log: function (message) {
                if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function") {
                    console.log(message);
                }
            }
        };

        return Logger;
    }());
```

But you have the same problem with `MyObject`, so you have to do

```
var MyObject = ( function() { .... } (Logger) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm wondering if you think the author should have defined the variable in his sample. Do you think by leaving it out of the tutorial it made the tutorial more difficult to understand.  Do you think he left it out because it's just common sense? why couldn't he just put in.

Comment: urghhh .... looks like you've been victimized by a poorly written tutorial!  Not your fault, the author should have been more careful. I'm sure he knows the right way to do it, but he didn't pay attention to the details of how a novice might read his tut.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not storing the result returned by the anonymous function that cooks the `Logger` object.

```
var Logger = (function () {
    var Logger = {
        log: function (message) {
            if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function") {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }
    };

    return Logger;
}());
```

Now, you can use `Logger`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question.